# Parallel.Invoke same action executed

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm tryng to execute some actions in parallel:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var actions = new List<Action>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        actions.Add(() => DoSomething(i));
    }
    
    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
}

private static void DoSomething(int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("DoSomething number {0}", number));
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

But only the last action, with number parameter equals to 10 executed.
In the output I got 10 times the same value:

```
DoSomething number 10
```

[Click here for fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nGBhzg)

Comment: What is the actual value of `i` when the actions are executed? 10. This has nothing to do with `Parallel.Invoke`. Although using `Parallel.Invoke` like this is highly unusual. You probably need `Parallel.ForEach` instead

Comment: You are closing over the loop variable

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6SzKlJ

Comment: Try use `Parallel.For(0, 10, (i) => DoSomething(i));` instead.